# Chrome Inspector: View styles and box diaram side by side

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Earlier I was getting both styles and the box diagram in chrome inspector side by side as shown in below image.

[image]

And now after the latest update, I can see only 1 thing at a time, as shown in below image

[image]

Does someone know how to bring back the old layout?